# Using radio buttons to get data from PHP query

Tags: php

I have a random chat feature which allows users to randomly pair against another based on the parameters set by the user. The parameters are age (min: 17, max: 50) and gender (can chat with male, female, or any which means no preference).

When submit is clicked, it is easy to set queries if the radio values are `male` or `female`, because those are the values I am storing in my database, but I am unsure on how I can pair someone with another if the value is `any`.

Here are the radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</input> <br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</input><br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="any">Any</input>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Click to start chat! " />
```

P.s. The radio buttons are in a form but have no action.

```
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And here is my approach so far:

```
<?php
$age_from = @$_POST['age_from'];
$age_to = @$_POST['age_to'];
$gender = strip_tags(@$_POST['gender']);

if (isset ($_POST ['submit'])){
        // Chat with parameters script
        $any_chat = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age BETWEEN '$age_from' AND '$age_to' AND gender = '$gender' 
                                            ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
        $num_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows ($any_chat);
        while ($get_any_rand_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($any_chat)){
            $rand_name = $get_any_rand_user['username'];
            $acc_type = $get_any_rand_user['account_type'];

            if ($acc_type != "admin" ){ 
                if ($rand_name == $username){
                    $any_chat;
                    } else{
                        header ("Location: /messages.php?u=$rand_name");
                    }
            }       
            if ($num_of_rows == 0){
                echo "No results found. Try changing your query.";
                }
        } // while closed
}
?>
```

As you can see in the query `gender = '$gender'` can only retrieve a row if the gender is male or female (because they are the values in the db). But if `any` is selected, `$gender` will equal `any` which is not valid, since their is no user in my system with gender of any.

How can I work my way around this?

Comment: if the value is Any change the SQL string to remove the $gender restriction...

Comment: I strongly recommend using prepared statements because your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Look [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to learn how to do it with mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this. Create a variable to store your query and only add the gender condition if `$gender` is `male` or `female`.

```
<?php
$age_from = @$_POST['age_from'];
$age_to = @$_POST['age_to'];
$gender = strip_tags(@$_POST['gender']);

if (isset ($_POST ['submit'])){
        // Chat with parameters script

        $sql = "
            SELECT * 
            FROM users 
            WHERE age BETWEEN '$age_from' AND '$age_to' 
        ";
        if (!empty($gender) && ($gender == 'male' || $gender == 'female')) {
            $sql .= " AND gender = '$gender' ";
        }
        $sql .= " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ";
        $any_chat = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        $num_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows ($any_chat);
        while ($get_any_rand_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($any_chat)){
            $rand_name = $get_any_rand_user['username'];
            $acc_type = $get_any_rand_user['account_type'];

            if ($acc_type != "admin" ){ 
                if ($rand_name == $username){
                    $any_chat;
                    } else{
                        header ("Location: /messages.php?u=$rand_name");
                    }
            }       
            if ($num_of_rows == 0){
                echo "No results found. Try changing your query.";
                }
        } // while closed
}
?>
```

Comment: Andrew! Many thanks! This works a charm. Also, I have taken aboard your comment regarding prepare statements, and will surely implement more secure code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
     if (isset ($_POST ['submit'])){
    // Chat with parameters script
    $sql_builder = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age BETWEEN '$age_from' AND '$age_to'";
    if($gender != 'any'){
      $sql_builder .= "AND gender = $gender";
    }      
     $sql_builder .= "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";   
    $any_chat = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_builder);
```